# Avoiding table pagebreak if data exceeds limit

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

[image: Pagebreak To Table]

I am trying to generate a bill in PDF format.

In the given image as product are more that end table has gone to next page.

In that table there are 3 cells, one for left text with small font, other cell with middle text and next cell with that single line.

How can I prevent the table from breaking the page? Is there any property to get table to next page if a page break is going to occur?

I tried `table.SplitLate=false`, but it didn't work. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [PdfPTable.setKeepTogether(boolean)](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPTable.html#setKeepTogether%28boolean%29) ?

Comment: Yes I have used table.KeepTogether=true that worked thanks for ur response

Comment: Hi , can you please look at my this question. I am stuck with it. Can you please help me. 
link :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35909753/need-to-give-page-break-in-inner-pdfptable-of-itextsharp

Thanks